# How do the qualitative driving forces of a reaction make the reaction proceed?

Tags: thermodynamics

In high school chemistry, I learned that there are 4 “qualitative driving forces” that cause aqueous reactions to proceed:

1. Forming a solid (precipitate)
2. Forming a liquid
3. Forming a gas
4. Transferring electrons (redox)

I also learned about the 2 “quantitative driving forces” for general reactions to proceed:

1. Entropy
2. Enthalpy

While the two quantitative driving forces can be used to calculate whether a reaction is thermodynamically favorable through free energy calculations, I don’t see why the 4 qualitative driving forces are taught as reasons for predicting whether a reaction will occur.

In sum, my questions are: how are these four forces able to drive a reaction and are they related to entropy/enthalpy?

Comment: It's because of the entropic gain during the formation of a product which forms its own seperate phase from the reaction mixture, the first three are good signals. The fourth is a good signal because of its enthalpic implications.

Comment: I personally have problems with this idea of driving force. They seems rather descriptors of what is happening / happened rather then driving forces. Take 1. On its bases dissolving stuff would be impossible. This stuff doesn't make sense to me, even when the so called quantitative driving forces are put in the discussion as per Nisarg Bhavsar. I even think this might be your interpretation and not a teached concept. Moreover plenty of reactions as conducted don't see any phase change because most of them happen in solution. Curios about other users commenti...

Comment: @Alchimista The four "driving forces" are surely not fundamental but just are rules of thumb to blindly guess if a reaction has any potential to take place. You surely can't rely on them for either confirming or a denying a reaction, you can use them only to justify said reactions

Comment: @NisargBhavsar yes they are merely facts. They can happen or not. They are driving "forces" only when they are. Again I won't teach thermodynamics this way, not even at elementary level. I can perhaps use that slang with a senior colleague but not with a young student. So basically OP is right and s/he should proceed on.